# How can I darken the colour of these splines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, spline

As the number of data points grows, the splines become invisible against the back drop.
How can I darken the colour of the splines?
Or another method to correct this visibility issue?

```
  library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(mgcv)
    
    # Summer
    Summer <- mgcv::gamSim(eg=5,n=10000,dist="normal",scale=0.6,verbose=TRUE) %>%
      mutate(x = x2 * 20) %>%
      rename("Season" = x0) %>%
      mutate(Season = ifelse(Season == "1", "Summer", Season)) %>%
      filter(.,Season == "Summer") %>%
      select(y, x, Season)
    
    # Winter
    Winter <- mgcv::gamSim(eg=5,n=10000,dist="normal",scale=1.0,verbose=TRUE) %>%
      mutate(x = x1 * 20) %>%
      rename("Season" = x0) %>%
      mutate(Season = ifelse(Season == "3", "Winter", Season)) %>%
      filter(.,Season == "Winter") %>%
      select(y, x, Season)
    
    # Bind
    DF <- rbind(Summer, Winter)
    
    
    # Plot
    Plot <- DF %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Season)) +
      geom_jitter() +
      geom_point(shape=21, alpha = 0.5,  size=0.05) +
      geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 10),  lwd = 1.6)
    Plot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting the lines to stand out over the points, then I would adjust the `alpha` for `geom_jitter`. Part of the issue is that you are plotting points over the jitter. I don't think you need both of these (unless I'm missing something).

```
library(ggplot2)

Plot <- DF %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Season)) +
      geom_jitter(alpha = 0.2) +
      geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 10),  lwd = 1.6)

Plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `geom_jitter()` is creating points of full size and full opacity; instead, add `position = "jitter"` to `geom_point()` (I'm assuming you don't really want *both* jittered points and points in their original positions?)
2. I adjusted the `alpha` and `size` in your `geom_point()`, but you may want to play with them some more (i.e., decrease size and opacity as the sample size increases). If your data set gets really big you could experiment with `geom_hexbin()` instead.
3. I find that changing the background to white via `theme_bw()` (or even `theme_classic()`) makes it easier to see the values against the background.

You can't make the fitted lines darker (unless you want to switch to something like `scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))`), but if you want to see the confidence ribbons more clearly you could increase `alpha` and/or set the `fill` colour for them.

```
Plot <- DF %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Season)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, alpha = 0.7,  size=0.5, position = "jitter") +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 10),  lwd = 1.6) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot with splines and points]